# AngularJS binding issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, components

I am in the process of upgrading a large AngularJS 1.4 app to 1.5 using components instead of raw controllers.

I have a basic component looking like this:

```
 'use strict';

 angular.module('myModule').component('userComponent', {
 controllerAs: 'vm',
 bindings: {
    user: '<'
 },
 controller:
    function userComponent($http) {
      let vm = this;
      vm.user = "World";
 });
```

When I try to display the value of vm.user in the template, it does not show and there is no error in the console:

```
 <user-component>
    <h1>Hello {{vm.user}}</h1>
 </user-component>
```

Can you tell me what is wrong? This should be fairly simple and I am not sure why it is not doing the binding as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a `templateUrl` or `template` definition in your component, which are required.

You can add this `template:"<span>Name: {{vm.user}}</span>"` or link a html page. 
[You can read more in the documentation here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/docs/guide/component)

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('test', []).controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl() {});


  angular.module('test').component('userComponent', {
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindings: {
      user: '<'
    },
    controller: function UserComponent($http) {
      let vm = this;
      vm.user = "World";
    },
    template: "<span>Name: {{vm.user}}</span>"
  });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="test">
  <!-- components match only elements -->
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
    <user-component></user-component>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I do have templateUrl in my route.js file like this:     .state('operatorHome', {
                        url: '/user',
                        component: 'UserComponent',
                        views: {

                            '': {
                                templateUrl: 'templates/user/user.html'
                            }
                        },
                    })

Comment: I would like to add the templateUrl inside my component but this will create a 404 not found Error.

Comment: As George shown you, you can use `template` and write in directly your component your HTML template

Comment: @Zooly the template will be quite large, I'm not very comfortable in doing this.

Comment: @NizarB. Looking at [ui-routers documentation](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component) (which is what I assume you're using) the template/templateUrl has to be defined on the component, although you've mentioned that moving it causes a 404, can you not just update it to have the right relative url? Not knowing your project folder structure I can't answer what you'd need to change it to

Answer (score 1):

You can't fill a component template like that. 
You have to define a template linked to your component.

```
 'use strict';

 angular.module('myModule').component('userComponent', {
 controllerAs: 'vm',
 template: '<h1>Hello {{vm.user}}</h1>',
 bindings: {
    user: '<'
 },
 controller:
    function UserComponent($http) {
      let vm = this;
      vm.user = "World";
 });
```

Comment: shouldn't component names start with a lower case letter: `'userComponent'`?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yes they should, I forgot to mention that in my answer, plus there is a missing curly brace after the controller definition

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Good spot but this is not the actual issue. I edited my post to remove the upperCase component name. Thank you.